# Correct flip/mirror of pixels of an image?

Tags: c++

http://tinypic.com/r/fwubzc/5

That shows what a flip should be and what a mirror should be.

Code for both types of mirrors:

```
void mirrorLeftRight()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width/2; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int temp = pixelData[x][y];
                pixelData[x][y]=pixelData[width-x][y]
                pixelData[width-x][y]=temp;
            }
    }
}

void mirrorUpDown()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height/2; y++) {
                int temp = pixelData[x][y];
                pixelData[x][y]=pixelData[x][height-y]
                pixelData[x][height-y]=temp;
            }
    }
}
```

Does this seem right for mirrors?

And for flip, just a matter of using `width` and `height` w/o dividing by 2?

Comment: What happens if `height` is not even?

Comment: just realized I was using 'int temp' when I should have made Color temp, as pixelData is of class Color

Comment: jeff - when height it's even, then integer division returns the floor of half of height and all is well.  you don't have to flip the middle column/line as it's already in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above seems more like the correct way to Flip, not mirror.

Mirror I would guess that you not switch the pixels, but rather copy from one side to the other.

With mirror I would guess that you need to change

```
int temp = pixelData[x][y]; 
pixelData[x][y]=pixelData[width-x][y] 
pixelData[width-x][y]=temp;
```

to something like this only

```
pixelData[x][y]=pixelData[width-x][y]
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `width-1-x` instead of `width-x`, and `height-1-y` instead of `height-y`. Otherwise for x==0 you'll try to index [width], which is outside the array.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't work since you are *swapping* pixels while you just have to override the right part of the image with the left part. Same thing applies to the `mirrorUpDown`.

If you swap them you obtain a flip, if you overwrite them you obtain a mirror.

- mirrorLeftRight: take pixels from left half and use them to overwrite right part
- mirrorUpDown: take pixels from upper part and use them to overwrite lower one
- flip: in this case you don't overwrite but you swap pixels (source half it's not influent in this case)

Comment: so my examples are flips, not mirrors.
what do i change to make that code a mirror?

Comment: since it's homework you should try to figure out by yourself :) I already gave you enough hints..