# Is there a way to reverse the order of an array in C++?

Tags: c++

I am making a small photo program that takes a .ppm file and then applies filters such as negating red, green, blue, flip horizontally, and grey scale (the user selects which filters to apply). I figured everything out except I am having difficulties with the horizontal flip. I do not think it is necessary to post the WHOLE program as I am just experiencing difficulty in making one function. However, if it is required, then please let me know then I will post it.

Here are the sample functions that negates red, green, and blue.

```
void negate_red(int image[], int w, int h)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<h; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
    {
        image[(i*w+j)*3] = 255 - image[(i*w+j)*3];
    }
}

void negate_green(int image[], int w, int h)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<h; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
    {
        image[(i*w+j)*3+1] = 255 - image[(i*w+j)*3+1];
    }
}

void negate_blue(int image[], int w, int h)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<h; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
    {
        image[(i*w+j)*3+2] = 255 - image[(i*w+j)*3+2];
    }
}
```

To my understanding, in order to flip an image horizontally, you have to reverse the order of the array. For example, the first RGB values will be the last, correct? Is there a way to reverse the order of an array? I did some search before I asked this question, and I found this:
[Correct flip/mirror of pixels of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647376/correct-flip-mirror-of-pixels-of-an-image)

So if I am interpreting this correctly, I should start the function like this:

```
void flip (int image[], int w, int h)
{
for(int i = 0; i<h/2; i++)
     for(int j=0; j<w/2; j++)
  {
  //code
  }
}
```

Now is there a way to reverse the order of the array to make it start for the last element and go to the first?

Any help is appreciated, and thank you so much! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there's a way.

Comment: @Almo Epic answer. Just epic.

Comment: I need some clarification here. How did you read the image? Did you read it 4 bytes at a time, reading a single RGB triple into one integer? Or did you read R into one `int`, G into the next `int` and B into the final `int`?

Answer (score 4):

**I would recommend [`std::reverse()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/) from `<algorithm>`. You can pass an array to it by invoking it with `(arr, arr+size)`. It will reverse the array.**

To address the discussion below: while it is somewhat odd to represent something like an RGB value as 3 independent ints in a language other than plain C, this should not be a problem for  OP: Ensure that the size of the array is a multiple of 3, define a struct like this:

```
struct rgb_value {
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
};
```

then cast the array to struct rgb_value, and invoke reverse with (cast_array, cast_array + original_size/3). This way the order inside the structs will be maintained.

I kind of don't like the idea of doing casts like this myself, but the alternatives are to write an own reverse function, which does the swaps maintaining rgb-order, or copying the data to a data-structure, where the rgb-values are represented as such and swapped properly.

Edit 2: First of all I would like to point out, that this is not an answer to "How do you flip an image horizontally?", but to "Is there a way to reverse the order of an array in C++?". Therefor I tried to avoid the issue of whether the OP's image-flipping algorithm was correct as much as possible to stay on topic.

Second, even assuming that OP's algorithm was originally wrong, reverse would be the algorithm of choice. What other solutions suggest is nothing else than a fairly complicated way of saying:

```
rgb_color *pos = reinterpret_cast<rbg_color *>(image);
for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i){
    pos += i * rgb_per_row //select row
    std::reverse(pos, pos + rgb_per_row);//reverse row
}
```

with rgb_per_row being that length of a row divided by `sizeof(rgb_value)/sizeof(int)`,

Comment: There's a standard algorithm for *everything*.

Comment: This would reverse the RGB values, though, wouldn't it?

Comment: It would reverse the order of items in the array. It would not reverse the byte order of the values stored in the array. The first item would become the last and the last item would become the first.

Comment: @BenKey Right. That makes sense, given that an RGB triple would occupy the space of one `int`. I was thinking in `char` for some reason. But reversing the 1D array won't mirror the image along one axis. It would flip it across both?

Comment: @BenKey: eigenchris is right. If you look at Aaron's code you will see each RGB value is stored in an `int`, and image is an array of `int`s. So if you reverse the array that corresponds to a line you won't only flip the picture horizontally, you will also swap the colours. R1G1B1_R2G2B2, once reverted, would give B2G2R2_B1G1R1, but what you want is R2G2B2_R1G1B1. Red and blue would be swapped, whereas the green component would be right.

Comment: This won't work, since the array (while being 1D), represents a 2D object. Reversing it like that will rotate it 180%, while it flipping is done horizontally or vertically. This can howevver be handled by calling `std::reverse` on a different range, multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

You need to loop through each pixel on the left side of the image and flip it with its corresponding pixel on the right side. That means you need to look at each line in the whole image but only go halfway through the line.

```
void swap_int (int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = temp;
}

void h_flip (int image[], int w, int h)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<h; i++) // every row
         for(int j=0; j<w/2; j+=3) // halfway through the row
      {
          // We now swap this pixel (i,j) with its mirror pixel
          // on the right (i,w-j), swapping red, green, and blue values
          swap_int (&image [(i*w + j) * 3 + 0], &image [(i*w + (w-j)) * 3 + 0]);
          swap_int (&image [(i*w + j) * 3 + 1], &image [(i*w + (w-j)) * 3 + 1]);
          swap_int (&image [(i*w + j) * 3 + 2], &image [(i*w + (w-j)) * 3 + 2]);
      }
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that seems to realize an image is 2D and not 1D.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz But you are not swapping the pixels if you do this! You are only modifying the left half of the image. The right half will stay the same. Basically if the original row is like `abcd` , what you want is a `dcba`. Your code will give `dccd`. What you are doing, in other words, is mirroring the right half, not flipping the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterative way:
1) Initialize start and end indexes. 
start = 0, end = n-1
2) In a loop, swap arr[start] with arr[end] and change start and end as follows.
start = start +1; end = end – 1

/* Function to reverse arr[] from start to end*/
void reverseArray(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
  int temp;
  while(start < end)
  {
    temp = arr[start];   
    arr[start] = arr[end];
    arr[end] = temp;
    start++;
    end--;
  }   
}
```

Try applying this solution to your problem.