# Flip picture horizontal c++ without 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, image

I would like to know if there is anyway to horizontally flip an image without the use of a 2d array. Something similar to this:

```
     for (int x = 0; x < width/2; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                   int temp = pixelData[x][y]; 
                   pixelData[x][y]=pixelData[width-x][y] 
                   pixelData[width-x][y]=temp;
                }
        }
```

Comment: An image *is* a 2d array... What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: you could do `pixelData[width * x + y]`.

Comment: The algorithm you propose seems ok to me (apart that you need to replace `width-x` occurrences with `width-1-x`), what is that you don't like exactly? Maybe it could help if you try to describe your input and desired output. Please edit your question.

Comment: You can take ideas from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842814/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-the-order-of-an-array-in-c/28843009#28843009. It deals with 3 subpixels, red, green and blue, but it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single pointer into the image.

You will need to know the distance (amount to increment the pointer) between the end of one raster line (scanline) to the next.  So after you increment past the end of a raster line, add the distance to the pointer, so you end up at the left most column on the next raster line.

With modern systems, that have smart GPUs, you may have better efficiency by copying an image to a 2d-array, transforming it, then putting it back.  Smarter GPUs may have a mirroring function along with bit-blitting.